# how to do http post json data

Tags: angularjs

i am new in programming and angular.
i have the data like this in my controller

```
temanService.create({
    Userid: $scope.datateman.userid,
    Address: $scope.datateman.address,
    Employeeid: $scope.datateman.employeeid,
    Email: $scope.datateman.email,
    Phoneno: $scope.datateman.phoneno,
    Password: $scope.datateman.password,
    Division: $scope.datateman.division,
    Leavebalance: $scope.datateman.leavebalance
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.showAlert({
        title: "Information",
        message: "Data Telah Tersimpan"
    });
});
```

and this is my service for http.request

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .factory('temanService', function($http) {
        var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:60820/MobileBootcamp.svc/';
        return {
            create: function(datateman) {
                return $http.post(baseUrl + 'insert?method=insertuser',
                    datateman, // <--- what to insert here
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                        }
                    });
            },
            update: function(datateman) {
                return $http.post(baseUrl + 'update.php', datateman, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
                    }
                });
            },
            delete: function(id) {
                return $http.get(baseUrl + 'delete.php?id=' + id);
            }
        };
    });
```

and this is example of the correct parameter for insert

```
{
    "Value": "userid|address|employeeid|email|phoneno|password|division|leavebalanc"
}
```

My question is,

How to put data to the http request post method?

i wanted to make like this

```
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://110.35.82.163:9090/MobileBootcamp.svc/insert?    method=insertnews',
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        data: { "Value": userID + "|" + $scope.title + "|" + $scope.posttag + "|" + $scope.content }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var data = {
    Userid: $scope.datateman.userid,
    Address: $scope.datateman.address,
    Employeeid: $scope.datateman.employeeid,
    Email: $scope.datateman.email,
    Phoneno: $scope.datateman.phoneno,
    Password: $scope.datateman.password,
    Division: $scope.datateman.division,
    Leavebalance: $scope.datateman.leavebalance
};
var dataCollection = [];
for(var item in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(item)){
        dataCollection.push(data[item]);        
    }
}
var DTO = {
    Value: dataCollection.join('|');
};
//do not use success. its obsolete
temanService.create(DTO).then(function(response){

},function(response){
    //error
});
```

Writing service like this will be more readable.

```
create: function(datateman) {
    var config = {
        method: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + 'insert?method=insertuser',
        data: datateman,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };
    return $http(config);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

In your code you can do

```
var data = { "Value": datateman.userID + "|" + $scope.title + "|" + $scope.posttag + "|" + $scope.content } + 'your next values'.

    $http.post(baseUrl+'insert?method=insertuser', JSON.stringify(data) ,{
                headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            });
```

Comment: it didnt work, i really need to write the {"Value" : "parameters"} so my restclient can receive the parameters

Comment: @AnggaGilang what is the look of your expected data?

Comment: i need to make like this one :

method: 'POST',
url: 'http://110.35.82.163:9090/MobileBootcamp.svc/insert?     method=insertnews',
crossDomain: true,
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
data: { "Value": userID + "|" + $scope.title + "|" + $scope.posttag + "|" + $scope.content }

@Suren Srapyan

Answer (score 1):

Just add data attribute to your service.

For your code add like the following

```
create: function (datateman){
    return $http.post(baseUrl+'insert?method=insertuser',datateman,{
       headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    });
```